# Clarification for using functions like row() and row_array(), etc

Tags: php, codeigniter

I was reading the page https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html
and I read if `$row = $query->first_row()` this gives `object`
and if `we want this as array` then we have to use
`$row = $query->first_row('array')` and this is `ok`.

But, can we replace these functions?

```
$row = $query->row(); //for object
```

and 
    `$row = $query->row_array(); //for array`
 to a single function with `different parameter`.

Also if these functions have parameters like `index,class` then we can use the above `functions` like

```
$row = $query->row(array('index'=>5,'type'=>'array','class'=>'Users'));
 //for array mentioned type here
$row = $query->row(array('index'=>5,'type'=>'object','class'=>'Users'));
 //for object mentioned type here
```

Need some **Guidance**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`to a single function with different parameter.` i think you are asking for a core system file modification here.. which is not good at all...why???  because what if you need to update your codeigniter version later on...you need to update your core files for that which in turn will replace your modified code....

anyways..the only difference between these two function  (row and row_array) is.. `row` returns the datas as object whereas `row_array()` returns in array.....

what row() does is it gets single result in object...

> This function returns a single result row. If your query has more than one row, it returns only the first row. The result is returned as an object.

example

```
 $query=$this->db->query('select * from table where id= "1"');
 $row=$query->row() //these returns i object
 $row=$query->row_array() //this returns in array..
```

however you  can pass two optional parameters to row() function.. one being the row number of specific rows return... if not mentioned it returns the first row.. and second which is , name of a class to instantiate the row with.. you can go through the guide..for more information